# Div's height becomes 0 when I set a percentage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have `li's` with the `flexlayout`. There are 3 `li's` in every column. (`flex-basis` is set to a third.) In the `li` I have a `div` for a background image, and another `div` to display text. I want the text to be below the image. The image should take up a majority of the room.

For some reason the `image` isn't there. I set the `image` height to `80%`, but when I run it and go to "inspect element" (in chrome), the `div's` height is 0. When I set it to an amount with pixels, (not percentage), then it works.

My question is, how can I set the `div` to a percentage and still have it shown?

#### JSFiddle

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:aqua;
}
ul {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    height: calc(70% + 0px);
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
    /* Subtract the border */
    color: firebrick;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    background-color: greenYellow;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 200px;
}
.image {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nswXRR4.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50%, 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">4</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: % width / height only gets set if the parent has a width / height. Without really looking at what you have, I'd say it's likely that you are trying to set a  % height on a block element within an inline element (inline elements have no "height").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `li` has a height defined by `flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);`, when dealing with percentages, browsers normally interpret the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) to mean height as defined by the `height` property.

In my experience, `min-height`, `max-height` and `flex-basis` have never worked as a height for a parent element when [dealing with percentage heights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276). Only `height` works, even though it doesn't explicitly say this must be the way in the spec. (Update: [Firefox may be broadening its interpretation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589502/3597276))

You can make this adjustment:

Instead of: `flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);`

Use: `height: calc(100%/3 - 2px);`

***HOWEVER...***

Based on what you wrote:

> In the `li` I have a `div` for a background image, and another `div` to
>   display text. I want the text to be below the image. The image should
>   take up a majority of the room.

... this doesn't have to be an issue about percentage heights. You can leave the `flex-basis` on the `li`, make the `li` a flex container, and then apply flex properties to the image and text.

Make this adjustment to the `li`:

```
li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
    /* Subtract the border */
    color: firebrick;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    background-color: greenYellow;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 200px;

    display: flex; /* new */
    flex-direction: column; /* new */
}
```

Then adjust the image and text:

```
.image {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nswXRR4.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50%, 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 5px;
    /* height: 90%; remove */
    flex: 10 1 auto; /* new */
}

.num {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0113ney/5/)

NOTE: `flex: 10 1 auto;` means `flex-grow: 10`, `flex-shrink: 1`, `flex-basis: auto`. In other words, the flex item can consume up to 10x more available space than siblings with `flex-grow: 1`, shrink evenly in proportion with siblings having `flex-shrink: 1`, and its initial main size is based on content size.

Comment: I revised my answer. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like the update!! In my actual project I have an `<a>` in each `li`, then the `.image` & `.num`, so nothing changes when I add what you wrote. Also, Is there a way to make the `.image`'s height more and the `.num` less?

Comment: Having the `<a>` in the `<li>` is not a big deal. You just need to add another flexbox so the flex properties can apply another level down. And to make the image bigger, you can play with the image size, or make the text font smaller, remove padding, etc. There are lots of options.

Comment: Here's a demo with `<a>` and smaller `.num` text: http://jsfiddle.net/o0113ney/6/

Answer (score 1):

Your `li` doesn't have a defined `height` property. Your `.image` div is then trying to become `90%` of undefined. You can guess what that is: 0.

Depending on what you want, you can set your `li` to be `display:flex` and then allow your `.image` div to grow more than your `.num` div as below.

There are more ways to modify the `flex: 10 1 0` or `flex: 1 0 0` properties, to get exactly what you are looking for, but the below code is an example:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:aqua;
}
ul {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    height: calc(70% + 0px);
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
    /* Subtract the border */
    color: firebrick;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    background-color: greenYellow;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 200px;
    display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.image {
     flex: 10 1 0; 
 }

.num {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.image {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nswXRR4.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50%, 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="num">4</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this is: `flex: 10 1 0` or maybe send a link to a tutorial? (I'm still learning.)

Comment: Didn't I set a height using `flex-basis`? I thought `flex-basis` defines either the height or width depending whether it's column or rows