# Height is not correct in flexbox items in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a delicate problem for any CSS guru out there.
My green div has a flexible height, taking up the remaining.
And now I want to put a div inside that div which should be the half of the green div. But it seems like if Chrome treats it like half of the whole page rather than the flex item.

http://jsfiddle.net/unh5rw9t/1/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            1
        </div>
        <div id="content">2
            <div id="half_of_content">2.1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu {
    height: 70px; 
    background-color: purple
}

#content {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#half_of_content {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: cyan
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could absolutely position `div id="half_of_content"`.

```
#content {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative; /* new */
}

#half_of_content {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute; /* new */
    width: 100%; /* new */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/unh5rw9t/3/)

With regard to your statement:

> But it seems like if Chrome treats it like half of the whole page
>   rather than the flex item.

You gave the `body` a `height: 100%`. Then gave its child (`.wrapper`) a `height: 100%`. Then gave its child (`.content`) a `height: 100%`. *So they're all equal height.* Giving the next child (`#half_of_content`) a `height: 50%` would naturally be 50% height of `body`.

With absolute positioning, however, [you don't need to specify parent heights](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height).

Comment: This actually looks better than Oriols solution, although this can seems even more ugly I think. But until Chrome fixed the bug, I will use the easiest method there is.

Comment: Well, if I could I would want to avoid setting the height:100% on #wrapper since it already receives a height from flexbox. But then I cant do 50% height on the child element because ... I dont know why..

So we can officially say that **flexitems that grows doesn't receive their actual height** ?

Comment: *Ugly??*  I see a thing of beauty in that solution :-) The 50% `div` expands and contracts beautifully, gracefully and precisely in the parent `div`.

Comment: Just to be clear, cause I'm not sure which `div` you're talking about,  `#half_of_height` in *not* a flex item.

Comment: the 50% means taking half of the parents height. But in this case, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

[@Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b) [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589536/1529630) why Chrome behaves like this:

> You gave the `body` a `height: 100%`. Then gave its child (`.wrapper`)
>   a `height: 100%`. Then gave its child (`.content`) a `height: 100%`.
>   *So they're all equal height.* Giving the next child (`#half_of_content`) a `height: 50%` would naturally be a 50% height
>   of `body`.

However, Firefox disagrees because, in fact, that `height: 100%` of `.content` is ignored and its height is calculated according to `flex: 1`.

That is, Chrome resolves the percentage with respect to the value of parent's `height` property. Firefox does it with respect to the resolved flexible height of the parent.

The right behavior is the Firefox's one. According to [Definite and Indefinite Sizes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite-sizes),

> If a percentage is going to be resolved against a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item)’s
>   [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size), and the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) has a [definite](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite) [flex
>   basis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis), and the [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) has a [definite](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite) [main
>   size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size), the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item)’s [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) must be treated as
>   [definite](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite) for the purpose of resolving the percentage, and the
>   percentage must resolve against the **flexed** [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) of the
>   [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) (that is, after the layout algorithm below has been
>   completed for the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item)’s [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container), and the [flex
>   item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) has acquired its final size).

Here is a workaround for Chrome:

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#content::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
#half_of_content {
  flex: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

This way the available space in `#content` will be distributed equally among `#half_of_content` and the `::after` pseudo-element.

Assuming `#content` doesn't have other content, `#half_of_content` will be `50%`. In your example you have a `2` in there, so it will be a bit less that `50%`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: purple
}
#content {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#content::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
#half_of_content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menu">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="content">2
    <div id="half_of_content">2.1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will I be able to use normal height percentage calculations inside the #half_of_content container without doing the ugly fixes? Because I am going to divide up the space a lot later..

Comment: @Doodlemeat Since `#half_of_content` has `height: auto`, you can't use percentages in the `height` of its children. But you can use the same trick again, e.g. if you want a child to be `70%` set `flex: 70` and add a pseudo-element with `flex: 100`.

Comment: That's an interesting distinction between Chrome & FF. I think traditionally, when calculating percentage heights, browsers have interpreted the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) to mean height as defined by the `height` property. I've never seen `min-height`, `max-height` or `flex-basis` (until now) work on a parent when [dealing with percentage heights](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276).

Comment: The spec, which is a bit old as you point out, seems to require a height (generic term) but not a `height`, although `height` is the predominant implementation. Looks like FF is loosening its interpretation.

Comment: @Michael_B IMO the Firefox implementation of using the resolved height instead of the value of `height` makes more sense. The other day I found another interesting case in which the height of the container didn't depend directly on the height of the content, but it did through `min-height: auto`. I guess we will have to wait until a new spec clarifies those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting flexboxes is a little buggy. I reworked your markup a little by adding an inner wrapper with `display: flex;` which seems to do the job. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5zafgg1/1/) (also using class names instead of ids).

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    2
    <div class="half">
      2.1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper-inner {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

on `#content` set

```
display: flex; 
flex-flow: column nowrap; 
justify-content: flex-end
```

on `#half_of_content` set `flex: 0 0 50%`;

Caveat: you need to add an `extra` div as a child of `#content`.

Here's the full example:

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu {
    height: 70px; 
    background-color: purple
}

#content {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: green;
}

#half_of_content {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: cyan
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            1
        </div>
        <div id="content">2
            <div id="half_of_content">2.1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```