# Flexbox in Chrome--How to limit size of nested elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

In Google Chrome, how do I force an element nested inside of a member of a flexbox (by "member of a flexbox" I mean a child of an element styled with `display:flex`) to limit its size to the size of the flexbox member it's nested under?  For example, suppose I have the following:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:100vh;">
  <div style="height:60px;">Static header</div>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 0; overflow:hidden;">
     <div style="overflow:auto; height:100%;" id="problem-is-here">
       Lots and lots of content, way too much to fit in the viewport
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because the first child `div` of the outermost `div` has a constant height, it ends up exactly 60px tall, and because the second child `div` has a `flex-grow` of 1, it gets the rest of the space available (in this case, 100% of the viewport minus 60px). I can confirm that this element's dimensions according to Inspect Element are just large enough to take up the rest of the viewport space.

In Firefox and IE11, due to the `height:100%`, the innermost element (`id="problem-is-here"`) takes on the height computed for its parent.  Therefore, since it is too small to display its content and `overflow` is set to `auto`, it (and not the entire `body`) gets a vertical scrollbar.  This is what I want.

In Chrome, however, the innermost element is rendered with enough height to contain all of its content, which is a larger height than its parent.  Thus, because its parent has `overflow:hidden`, no scrollbar appears and the excess content is inaccessible.  How do I tell Chrome to render this innermost element with height at most equal to that of its parent, when the parent height is determined by a flexbox, not a CSS `height` property?  Note that I can't give either the innermost `div` or its parent a definite `height` value since in the application I'm working on, the number of other flexbox members can vary.

Note:  I have tried a few suggestions from other answers, such as setting all elements to have `min-height:0` instead of `auto`, or ensuring `flex-basis` is set to `0`, but none of these have worked.  See

http://plnkr.co/edit/UBRcrNmR5iDbn3EXu6FI?p=preview

for an example that illustrates the problem.  (The `div` with id `heres-the-problem` is the one whose height I want limited to the height of its parent.)

Comment: is this what you look for ? http://plnkr.co/edit/lxCkObgKgpEf0GYZbQtx?p=preview less markup and less css. HINT: margin reset for body

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***First, let's tackle the terminology:***

> ...how do I force an element nested inside of a member of a flexbox (by "member of a flexbox" I mean a child of an element styled with `display:flex`) to limit its size to the size of the flexbox member it's nested under?

An element with `display: flex` is called a **flex container** (technically) or **flex parent** (colloquially).

The children of a flex container are called **flex items**. Note the word *children* (first-level). Descendents of a flex container beyond the children are not flex items and most flex properties don't apply to them.

---

***Now, addressing your question:***

The problem is that Firefox (and apparently IE11) have a different interpretation of the percentage height rule than Chrome.

Specifically, the vertical scrollbar you want is not rendering in Chrome because you're using percentage heights in a way that doesn't conform with the traditional implementation of the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height).

> [**CSS `height` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)
>
> **percentage**
>  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to "auto".
>
> **auto**
>  The height depends on the values of other properties.

In other words, if you want an element to have a percentage height, then you must specify a height on the containing block (i.e. the parent).

In your code, `body` (level 1) has `height: 100vh`.

One level down, `.max-flex` (level 2) has `height: 100%`.

Four levels down, `.large-nested-div` (level 4) has `height: 100%`.

However, at `.variable-flex-content` (level 3), there is no `height` property. You are defining the height with `flex: 1 1 0`. As far as Chrome is concerned, this is a missing link in the chain and a violation of the spec. Chrome is expecting to see the `height` property, and when it doesn't, it computes the height to `auto`.

---

***Chrome vs Firefox*** (I haven't tested IE11, so I won't mention it here)

Traditionally, when calculating percentage heights, browsers have interpreted the spec's use of the term "height" to mean the value of the `height` property. It could just as easily be interpreted as a height (generic term), but the `height` property requirement has become the predominant implementation. I've never seen `min-height` or `max-height` work on a parent when dealing with percentage heights.

Recently, however, as noted in this question and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33589469/3597276) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276), Firefox has broadened its interpretation to accept `flex` heights, as well.

It's not clear which browser is more compliant.

It doesn't help matters that the `height` property definition hasn't been updated since 1998 ([CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/)).

---

***The Solution***

Instead of defining the height of `.variable-flex-content` with `flex: 1 1 0%`, try using `height: 100%` or `height: calc(100% - 60px)` or [absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589536/3597276).

Comment: Your suggestion of setting the `height` of `.variable-flex-content` would not work for me, as on the page I am working on, the total number of flex elements can change, and a static `height` would not work in all situations.  However, setting `.variable-flex-content` to `position:relative` and setting its child to `position:absolute` caused `height:100%` to behave the way I wanted.  See my updated plunk: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBRcrNmR5iDbn3EXu6FI?p=preview).  It produces the behavior I need as long as there is only one direct child of `.variable-flex-content`.

Comment: I figured as much. I was aware of the restriction from your question, but I included the `height` option anyway in case it became useful to you or others. My real solution for you was the absolute positioning. I was also going to suggest a nested flex box and `min-height` options, but didn't want the answer to get too long. I'm glad you got the issue resolved. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: More (and possibly better) solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276