# how to make a div a percentage of the overall body height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying a more fluid design.

I want specific divs to be a percentage of the overall body. I also want to set fluid / liquid padding within each div.

```
<body>
   <div class='image'></div>
   <div class='fourty'></div>
   <div class='sixty'></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 margin-top: 85px;
 min-height: 100%;
}

.image {
  content: image_url('something.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*I'm assuming the padding I'm setting is a percentage of the .fourty
  div not the overall body. Granted, width is 100%.*/
.fourty{
  padding: 4% 8%;
  min-height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sixty{
  padding: 4% 8%;
  min-height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

The problem I'm having is that the percentage height does not seem to take effect for these divs. It seems to just be an auto height based off the contents of the div.

How do I correct  / achieve this?  I'm open to a JS solution, but would be more interested as to how to accomplish this in CSS.

Comment: Try giving both the `body` and `html` 100% height.

Comment: Generally body is only as tall as the content, that is where people run into issues with height a lot. Is your parent elements height defined?

Comment: look into using `vh` which gets the viewport height. So `height: 100vh`

Comment: I tried setting height on the html as well - no change. Toni, the parent element of the body? Is what you're saying: every element on my page is percentage based, so the browser doesn't know what to make the body 100% of?

Comment: I think I may have figured out my own question.. Would the best solution just to be to set a min height, then the div would have to adjust to child content within?  So, my content is text-based. Set that to ems based off the body, and set margin and padding to percentages within the div...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work may help you

Answer (score 1):

As far as CSS goes, there are no styles that you can apply to make an element's height equal to a certain percentage of the total document (body) height.

CSS does, however, offer you options to style an element's heights to a certain percentage of the viewport height (using VH units), but since this does not achieve your goal, I'll leave you with a javascript answer that does.

Relevant javascript functions:

```
function getDocumentHeight() {
  return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);
};

function setDivHeight(target, percentage) {
    var desiredHeight = getDocumentHeight() * (percentage/100)
    target.style.height = desiredHeight + 'px';
};
```

To set the height initially and on viewport resizes:

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById('target');

setDivHeight(targetDiv);

window.addEventListener('resize', setDivHeight.bind(null, targetDiv))
```

Comment: *As far as CSS goes, there are no styles that you can apply to make an element's height equal to a certain percentage of the total document (body) height.* -- This is not correct. Percentage heights work just fine when used properly.

Comment: @Michael_B, could you explain how I can set an element's height to a  percentage of the total document?  I can only imagine hacks that would require someone to alter their HTML in a manner that almost always ends up to their detriment. CSS is unaware of total document height.

Comment: There is no problem (or hack needed) when using percentage heights on HTML elements. You just need to specify the height of the parent in most cases. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I'm having is that the percentage height does not seem to take effect for these divs. It seems to just be an auto height based off the contents of the div.

That is correct. The reason is that your code is in violation of the spec.

From the [**W3C `height` property definition**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height):

> **percentage**
>  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.
>
> **auto**
>  The height depends on the values of other properties.

In other words, if you're going to use percentage values, you'll need to use the `height` property from top to bottom.

From the browser's perspective, `min-height` (and `max-height`) don't adhere to this rule and, therefore, as the spec says, they compute to `auto`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0zquyb0p/) (with your code, revised)

Read more here: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

---

As an aside, I think its safe to say that the `height` definition is thoroughly obsolete. It hasn't been updated since 1998 ([CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/)) and there are many ways for establishing the height of a box. Confining percentage heights to only the `height` property doesn't make much sense anymore.

Firefox seems to agree. Recent versions now accept `flex` heights, as well. See examples here:

- [Height is not correct in flexbox items in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33589469/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)
- [Flexbox in Chrome--How to limit size of nested elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33789693/3597276)